# Convert hex digit to actual string value from page source

Tags: c#

I am running one code where i am splitting web page source of particular url and saving in the database. one of the web page it's showing some sentence in hindi but in page source it's showing hex digit value. which i am not able to convert in hindi.
Below is the example.

```
&#2342;&#2379;&#2361;&#2366;&#2405; &#2358;&#2381;&#2352;&#2368;&#2327;&#2369;&#2352;&#2369; &#2330;&#2352;&#2344; &#2360;&#2352;&#2379;&#2332; &#2352;&#2332; &#2344;&#2367;&#2332; &#2350;&#2344;&#2369; &#2350;&#2369;&#2325;&#2369;&#2352;&#2369; &#2360;&#2369;&#2343;&#2366;&#2352;&#2367; &#2404; &#2348;&#2352;&#2344;&#2313;&#2305; 
&#2352;&#2328;&#2369;&#2348;&#2352; &#2348;&#2367;&#2350;&#2354; &#2332;&#2360;&#2369; &#2332;&#2379; &#2342;&#2366;&#2351;&#2325;&#2369; &#2347;&#2354; &#2330;&#2366;&#2352;&#2367; &#2405; &#2348;&#2369;&#2342;&#2381;&#2343;&#2367;&#2361;&#2368;&#2344; &#2340;&#2344;&#2369; &#2332;&#2366;&#2344;&#2367;&#2325;&#2375;
```

But Actual value for this is:

```
दोहा॥ श्रीगुरु चरन सरोज रज निज मनु मुकुरु सुधारि । बरनउँ रघुबर बिमल जसु जो दायकु फल चारि ॥ बुद्धिहीन तनु जानिके
```

Can we convert this hex digit to actual string value like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#2342;&#2379;&#2361;&#2366;&#2405; &#2358;&#2381;&#2352;&#2368;&#2327;&#2369;&#2352;&#2369; &#2330;&#2352;&#2344; &#2360;&#2352;&#2379;&#2332; &#2352;&#2332; &#2344;&#2367;&#2332; &#2350;&#2344;&#2369; &#2350;&#2369;&#2325;&#2369;&#2352;&#2369; &#2360;&#2369;&#2343;&#2366;&#2352;&#2367; &#2404; &#2348;&#2352;&#2344;&#2313;&#2305;&#2352;&#2328;&#2369;&#2348;&#2352; &#2348;&#2367;&#2350;&#2354; &#2332;&#2360;&#2369; &#2332;&#2379; &#2342;&#2366;&#2351;&#2325;&#2369; &#2347;&#2354; &#2330;&#2366;&#2352;&#2367; &#2405; &#2348;&#2369;&#2342;&#2381;&#2343;&#2367;&#2361;&#2368;&#2344; &#2340;&#2344;&#2369; &#2332;&#2366;&#2344;&#2367;&#2325;&#2375;");
```

Outputs:

> "दोहा॥ श्रीगुरु चरन सरोज रज निज मनु मुकुरु सुधारि । बरनउँरघुबर बिमल जसु जो दायकु फल चारि ॥ बुद्धिहीन तनु जानिके"

Comment: Thanks Hillin, It's worked for me as i was expected. I am marking it as answer.